# ActionScript 3 width and height of asset locked at zero

Tags: actionscript-3

Every class I create from an asset in ActionScript 3 has a width and height which are both 0. If I set a value and then immediately trace it, the output is zero. The class is valid and the code runs, it just doesn't display anything. (Unless I use graphics methods.) Additionally, it remains locked at frame 0.

[screenshot of the setup http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9799/flashwtf.png](http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9799/flashwtf.png)

```
// in the main SWF class
titleScreen = new TitleScreen();
addChild(titleScreen);
trace("w: ", titleScreen.width, ", h: ", titleScreen.height);
titleScreen.width = 550;
titleScreen.height = 400;
trace("w: ", titleScreen.width, ", h: ", titleScreen.height);
```

Expected Output:

```
w: 200, h: 123
w: 550, h: 400
```

Actual output:

```
w: 0, h: 0
w: 0, h: 0
```

Comment: In fact, even the width and height properties of the main SWF object are locked. I don't understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because I'm exporting classes in frame 200. I did this in order to preload, which I did. But even when the entire document was loaded, width and height were locked at zero.

Solution: After preloading (the main instance's loaderInfo .bytesLoaded >= .bytesTotal), call the main instance's .gotoAndStop(200). (or whatever frame you exported classes in.) At this point all your classes and objects will be valid.